# Change CSS from hovering to clicking in visualization

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm very new to JS, CSS and HTML but feel very excited to explore it more.

My visualization and whole code is here:
https://gist.github.com/DariaAlekseeva/a71475378a5d12ea40bc

At the moment when I move mouse across object, many paths appear and it not easy to see details.

I'd like to change setting in visualization from hovering to clicking.
First I hover and active paths change. Then I pick one path, click on it and only this path stays active. And I still should be able to see appearing comments when I hover ONLY along this path. Then I need to "unclick" this path (or click outside object) and keep hovering until I find another path to click on.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify `mousemove` to `mousedown`. Then it will be changed to display tip for click event, but not 'hover'.

I created a plunkr for that, only display tip for clicking.
http://plnkr.co/edit/rn76z5z8cxZpqKKm7peN

(I modified the `mousemove` to `mousedown` at about 218 line.)

You can use 'mouseout', 'mousedown', 'mousemove' to implement these kinds of interaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like not just to change 'hover' into 'click' but also  when you click, activated element stays activated until I disactivate it by clicking on the same element or outside svg object. I'd also like to see activated elements while hovering. Summarizing:   
1. Moving mouse around elements and they get activated just by moving mouse.  
2. Click on element to FIX it activated to explore along it's lines.  
3. Unclick element  
4. Keep moving mouse around elements and be able activate them just by moving.